# Is there a data type for a datetime in RCF2822 format?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I want insert a timestamp in RCF2822 format, for example `Tue, 31 Dec 2013 23:00:00 +0000`. What data type do you recommend for this?

I need to have the datetime in RCF2822 format because I need the time zone in which it was generated so that it can also convert between many years.

In alternative, i can insert datetime in format ISO 8601, for example `2008-04-16T11:43:32+02:00`

Comment: And what is the *RCF2822* format?

Comment: @juergend: I'm sure datetime as defined by http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#section-3.3

Comment: I propose two columns: a) `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` as UTC to get the chronologic order and  b) local time with the same data type (preferred) or the offset to UTC as `TIME`.

Comment: You can refer to the official reference: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5322#section-3.3

Answer (score 0):

You should let the database decide how to store it. MySQL datetime [stores data in UTC](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html) internally. You could try to include the timezone in a separate column and use [Convert_Tz](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) as follows:

```
select convert_tz(datetimecolumn, timezonecolumn, 'Europe/Bucharest');
```

A list of timezones may be loaded into mysql using [mysql_tzinfo_to_sql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html) as follows:

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root mysql
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: `TIMESTAMP` is converted to UTC before storing, but not `DATETIME`, see the manual (your link): _MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval. (This does not occur for other types such as DATETIME.)_